# Adding a trigger to a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to place a trigger on a button, shown here:  http://jsfiddle.net/3gdc0ajs/4/
Once the button is clicked, the 'Home' page scrolls out of view and the About page scrolls into view.

I wrote this:

```
$('.cps-trigger').click(function() {
    .animate('slow'); 
});
```

I stuck this snippet of code into my .js file, between the last set of "});" and the comment "end dot nav*. The result was it completely stopped the vertical dot navigation, so I removed the snippet.  I'm pretty bad at writing jquery, but I'm trying.  Could someone shine some light on why my snippet of code isn't working?

Comment: Plain `.animate()` is a syntax error. Methods apply to objects, so you have to specify an object before the dot.

Comment: Oh okay. So I was missing something, an object. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a function that you will then call in the click event. If the click event is on an anchor tag you will need to prevent default. Example:

```
var scrollTo = function(id){

    // scroll to about section functionality
    var scrollPos = $(id).offset().top;
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollPos + 'px' }, 'slow');   

};

// your click event
$('.my-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollTo('#about');
});
```

Comment: I took out the a tags to see if your jquery snippet will work.  It didn't.  I placed it inside and outside of the last set of "});".   I used my 'what' class and replaced it with your '.my-button'.  I clicked the button, and nothing happened. No change in pages.   I also tried doing scrollTo(#about); and nothing happened.  Am I putting the code where it should be?

Comment: My code was just an example of how you could do it. You would have to replace the selectors with your own and add the functionality to scroll to different sections. But are you saying you don't have the code to make the scroll functionality work ?

Comment: I updated my code. You will need to change my-button to whatever your button is

Comment: ....woah. This worked. I guess I was missing alot more things than just an object.  Thank you so much for the help. Learned some things today.

Comment: no problem. if it worked you should mark my answer as the answer you used.

Answer (score 1):

You have a floating method call (I've made that term up I think!).

```
.animate('slow');
```

You're not specifying an object to call the method on so your syntax is invalid.  If you're trying to animate the button prefix it with this, so:

```
$(this).animate({
  // animation params
  }, 'slow');
```

If that's not the object you're trying to animate than you'll need to replace this with the actual object.  Either way, the above will prevent the rest of your code from breaking.

Comment: Nope, `$(this)`. Plain `this` is the DOM element, and DOM elements do not support `animate()`. You also have to specify *what* to animate, not only a duration.

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing those out, the solution seemed so obvious my brain went to sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
  $('.cps-trigger').click(function() {
        $(this).animate(
{scrollTop:posi}//or something else which you want for
,'slow'); // use current object to animate

    });
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.  :(  I placed it inside and outside of the last "});" on fiddle.